# Angular2 form control valueChanges observable complete never called

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm currently trying to show a simple loader on my search bar while the searching is taking place. I have planned to set a variable in the subscribe callback on the `valueChanges` observable from my form control to a value "loading", and to set it to an empty string in the complete callback. However, the complete callback is never called.

I have also tried adding a callback to finally on the observable, but it is also never called.

My code:

```
searchBox: Control = new Control();
loadingClass: string = "";

constructor() {
    this.searchBox.valueChanges
            .debounceTime(400)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribe((text: string) => {
                this.imageSearch = text;
                this.loadingClass = "loading";
            }, (err: Error) => {
                console.log(err);
            }, () => {
                this.loadingClass = "";
                console.log("test");
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I'm trying the wrong approach. Instead, I realized I had `debounceTime` on my observable, so I registered a `keyup` event on my input control, and in it set the value of `loadingClass` to `"loading"`, and in my subscribe I set the value back to an empty string.

Answer (score 5):

It's normal since the observable is never completed. The `valueChanges` allows you to receive value from your search box. In fact, you want to be notified when the search action is complete.

So I would try something like that, assuming that the `searchImage` actually does the search and return an observable:

```
constructor() {
  this.searchBox.valueChanges
              .debounceTime(400)
              .distinctUntilChanged()
              .flatMap((text:string) => { // <-------
                this.loadingClass = "loading";
                return this.searchImage(text);
              })
              .subscribe((searchResult) => {
                  this.imageSearch = searchResult;
                  this.loadingClass = ""; // <----
              }, (err: Error) => {
                  console.log(err);
              });
}
```

See this article for the use of the `flatMap` operator:

- https://jaxenter.com/reactive-programming-http-and-angular-2-124560.html

Comment: In my html template I actually have a pipe that depends on the this.imageSearch attribute, so I just set it in the subscribe part. Are there any adjustments to be made to your example so I can use it?

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get changes only when the validation has passed or check for validation in valueChanges?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could lead some people to get a better understanding of Angular2 Forms. Angular has two different approaches of building forms (Reactive and Template form). Not being aware of this could lead you to messy apps.

**valuesChages** is a property of the directive **NgModel**, and the class **FormControl** (keep it mind that).

> The reactive approaches use the **`ReactiveFormsModule import`**
>   (your.module.ts):

```
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
```

In this way you can use the `[(formControl)]` property on your form controls (template.component.html).

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchBox"
       required
       [(formControl)]="searchBox"/>
```

> Template-driven approached (your.module.ts):

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

    @NgModule({
      ...
      imports: [
        ...
        FormsModule,
        ...
      ],
      ...
    })
```

This approached has its own form control properties, **ngModel** (your.template.ts):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchBox"
       required
       [(ngModel)]="searchBox"/>
```